# Find the 10 largest files in a directory tree

Tags: c, recursion, file-system

I've recently finished a small project intended to better understand C. The program will output the ten largest files found (recursively in the event of subdirectories) in a specified directory.

I've just improved my code to use dynamic memory allocation instead of allocating (statically) a massive array. Please critique not only my use of dynamic memory allocation, but any additional anomalies or smells in terms of C conventions. The program compiles, runs, and outputs identical findings compared to the same program I implemented using Rust.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "fs_info.h"

/*
    A struct to contain the name of a filesystem entry and its size in bytes. 
    An array of this type will be used to catalog all filesystem entries for 
    the directory specified as command line argument.
*/
struct FS_Info {
    char name[1024];
    int size;
};

// initial size of array used to contain filesystem entries
int N = 100;

// number of largest entries to output
const int num_entries = 10;

// global pointer to current FS_Info array
// will be updated as the array is resized using dynamic memory allocation
struct FS_Info *curr_fs_info_ptr;

// determine the size of the info struct, used for qsort
const int info_size = sizeof(struct FS_Info);

// used to sort fs_entries array descending in terms of entry size
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    struct FS_Info *entryA = (struct FS_Info *)a;
    struct FS_Info *entryB = (struct FS_Info *)b;

    return (entryB->size - entryA->size);
}

void get_size(char *path)
{
    static int items_added = 0;

    struct stat st;
    if (stat(path, &st) == 0)
    {
        if (items_added < N) // if array capacity will not be exceeded
        {
            strcpy(curr_fs_info_ptr[items_added].name, path);
            curr_fs_info_ptr[items_added].size = st.st_size;

            items_added++;
        }
        else // double the size of the containing array
        {
            // puts("Re-allocating array to fit additional fs_entries");

            N *= 2;
            struct FS_Info *resized_fs_entries = realloc(curr_fs_info_ptr, N * sizeof(*curr_fs_info_ptr));
            if (resized_fs_entries)
            {
                curr_fs_info_ptr = resized_fs_entries;

                strcpy(curr_fs_info_ptr[items_added].name, path);
                curr_fs_info_ptr[items_added].size = st.st_size;

                items_added++;
            }
            else
            {
                puts("An error occurred when attempting to resize the array!");
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error getting stat for entry %s: %d\n", path, stat(path, &st));
    }
}

void walk(const char *currDir)
{
    DIR *dir = opendir(currDir);
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (dir == NULL) // directory could not be opened
    {
        return;
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
        // if directory is current dir or parent dir
        {
            continue;
        }

        char path_to_entry[1024];
        snprintf(path_to_entry, sizeof(path_to_entry), "%s/%s", currDir, entry->d_name);

        // use path_to_entry to call stats on the entry
        get_size(path_to_entry); // fs_entries will only be used on first call

        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
        {
            // recursively visit subdirectories
            walk(path_to_entry);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <target directory>\n", argv[0]);
    }

    const char *target_dir = argv[1];

    printf("Finding %d largest files in: %s\n", num_entries, target_dir);

    /* Create a pointer to the start of the FS_Info array and set the global
        variable curr_fs_info_ptr to this memory address
    */
    struct FS_Info *fs_entries = malloc(N * sizeof(struct FS_Info));
    curr_fs_info_ptr = fs_entries;

    // recursively visit all entries in the specified directory
    walk(target_dir);

    // sort the entries descending by file size
    qsort(curr_fs_info_ptr, N, info_size, compare);

    // output ten largest files found
    for (int i = 0; i < num_entries; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t%d\n", curr_fs_info_ptr[i].name, curr_fs_info_ptr[i].size);
    }

    free(curr_fs_info_ptr); // good practice, but program is over and OS will reclaim anyways 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw, thanks for bringing this to my attention, and my sincere apologies.  I had placed the struct definition in a header file when working on this originally, and missed the include statement when posting. Thanks for taking the time to provide such an instructive review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## General Observations

Good job checking all possible compiler errors and warnings.

It appears that the contents of `fs_info.h` are already included, so that include should be removed. In the future include those include files that you have written.

The code isn't completely portable because the header file `dirent.h` does not exist on Windows 10 systems using Visual Studio 2022. It does compile fine when the include for `fs_info.h` is removed on Linux systems (Ubuntu in my case).

Rather than `return 0;` at the end of the program the use of [`EXIT_SUCCESS`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status) will make the code more readable, in the examples below I use `EXIT_FAILURE` in the cases where the program should exit due to a problem. These symbolic constants are defined in `stdlib.h` for the C programming language and `cstdlib` for C++.

## Error Handling

There is insufficient error handling, at least in the case where the number of arguments is checked. The program should exit at this point if there is an error, due to the lack of error handling when a user doesn't provide a directory to search the code crashes.

Errors should be reported to `stderr` rather than `stdout` so instead of using `printf()` errors should be printed using `fprintf(stderr, ERROR_MESSAGE);`

```
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <target directory>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

## Test for Possible Memory Allocation Errors

In modern high-level languages such as C++, memory allocation errors throw an exception that the programmer can catch. This is not the case in the C programming language. While it is rare in modern computers because there is so much memory, memory allocation can fail, especially if the code is working in a limited memory application such as embedded control systems. In the C programming language when memory allocation fails, the functions `malloc()`, `calloc()` and `realloc()` return `NULL`. Referencing any memory address through a `NULL` pointer results in **undefined behavior** (UB).

Possible unknown behavior in this case can be a memory page error (in Unix this would be call Segmentation Violation), corrupted data in the program and in very old computers it could even cause the computer to reboot (corruption of the stack pointer).

To prevent this **undefined behavior** a best practice is to always follow the memory allocation statement with a test that the pointer that was returned is not null.

```
    /* Create a pointer to the start of the FS_Info array and set the global
        variable curr_fs_info_ptr to this memory address
    */
    struct FS_Info* fs_entries = malloc(N * sizeof(struct FS_Info));
    if (!fs_entries)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Malloc of fs_entries failed in main\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

**Note** Personally I would have used `calloc( size_t num, size_t size )` rather than `malloc()` in the memory allocation above. One of the benefits of `calloc()` is that it initializes the memory allocated to null values.

## Convention When Using Memory Allocation in C

When using `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` in C a common convention is to use `sizeof *PTR` rather than `sizeof(PTR_TYPE)`; this makes the code easier to maintain and less error prone, since less editing is required if the type of the pointer changes.

```
    struct FS_Info* fs_entries = malloc(N * sizeof(*fs_entries));
    if (!fs_entries)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Malloc of fs_entries failed in main\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

In the code there is a constant called `info_size` for `qsort()`; it might be better to use

```
    qsort(curr_fs_info_ptr, N, sizeof(*curr_fs_info_ptr), compare);
```

## Avoid Global Variables

It is very difficult to read, write, debug and maintain programs that use global variables. Global variables can be modified by any function within the program and therefore require each function to be examined before making changes in the code. In C and C++ global variables impact the namespace and they can cause linking errors if they are defined in multiple files. The [answers to this Stack Overflow question](//stackoverflow.com/q/484635) provide a fuller explanation.

## Variable Names

There must be a more descriptive variable name than `N` for the number of items in the array.

The function name `get_size()` is misleading, since there is a call to `realloc()` in this function. It isn't just getting the size; it is changing the size. Which size is it supposed to get, the size of the file or the size of the allocated array?

Comment: Er, `calloc()` initialises with _zero bytes_, which are not necessarily "null values" for the relevant type...

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation of dynamic memory allocation looks good.
Well organized and easy to follow.
There are a few things I noticed:

- You should check for errors for `opendir` and `readdir`. These functions can fail, you should check and handle the error appropriatly
- The same you should to when using `malloc` this will return `NULL` if it was not successfull
- You should replace `stat` with `fstat` to get the file information.`fstat` is faster because it avoid the overhead of `stat` which includes opening and closing a file

  - If you want to read in files bigger than the maximum of the `st_size` field of the `stat` struct which is about 9200 petabytes you need to use `fopen` and `fread`.
- The variable `N` should be used as a parameter to the `get_size` function instead of beeing used as a global variable, to make the function more modular and easier to reuse
- You could also use `qsort_r` instead of `qsort` for the array of `FS_Info` structs. `qsort_r` allows to pass a comparison function as a parameter, so you don't need to rely on a global function like `compare`. This would make it more convenient if you need to sort multiple arrays with different comparison functions.
- It is also a good practice to use `size_t` for array indices and array sizes, because it is an unsigned integer type which is guaranteed to represent the size of any object in memory.
- It would also be better if you define `FS_Info` as a type with `typedef` like this

```c
typedef struct {
    char name[1024];
    int size;
} FS_Info;
```

- You could also use `perror` instead of `puts`. This will print the error messages corresponding to the value of `errno`. This could be more informative.
- You could also use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` in the `get_size` function to prevent buffer overflows. If you leave your code like that is not neccesary because you are already using `snprintf` to prevent `path_to_entry` to overflow so therefore the string at the `path` pointer can't be longer than the `name` buffer in the `FS_Info` struct. It is still a good practice to use `strncpy`

```c
strncpy(curr_fs_info_ptr[items_added].name, path, sizeof(curr_fs_info_ptr[items_added].name) - 1);
```

- Since C strings are null-terminated you should substract 1 from the size of the destination buffer to make sure there is enough room for the null terminator at the end.

```c
char path_to_entry[1024];
snprintf(path_to_entry, sizeof(path_to_entry) - 1, "%s/%s", currDir, entry->d_name);
path_to_entry[sizeof(path_to_entry) - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: `strncpy()` costs the O(`sizeof ,name[1024]`).  Instead consider `strncat()`, `snprintf()`.

Answer (score 3):

When I compile this program (after removing the `#include` of the missing and unnecessary header), I get a few warnings about unsafe numeric conversions:

```
gcc-12 -std=c17 -fPIC -gdwarf-4 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wconversion  -Wstrict-prototypes -fanalyzer    -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE    282156.c    -o 282156
282156.c: In function ‘get_size’:
282156.c:50:50: warning: conversion from ‘__off_t’ {aka ‘long int’} to ‘int’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   50 |             curr_fs_info_ptr[items_added].size = st.st_size;
      |                                                  ^~
282156.c:59:78: warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
   59 |             struct FS_Info *resized_fs_entries = realloc(curr_fs_info_ptr, N * sizeof(*curr_fs_info_ptr));
      |                                                                              ^
282156.c:65:54: warning: conversion from ‘__off_t’ {aka ‘long int’} to ‘int’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   65 |                 curr_fs_info_ptr[items_added].size = st.st_size;
      |                                                      ^~
282156.c: In function ‘main’:
282156.c:129:43: warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
  129 |     struct FS_Info *fs_entries = malloc(N * sizeof(struct FS_Info));
      |                                           ^
282156.c:136:29: warning: conversion to ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
  136 |     qsort(curr_fs_info_ptr, N, info_size, compare);
      |                             ^
282156.c:136:32: warning: conversion to ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
  136 |     qsort(curr_fs_info_ptr, N, info_size, compare);
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~
```

These should be easy enough to fix.

---

Let's have a look at the comparison function:

> ```
> int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
> {
>     struct FS_Info *entryA = (struct FS_Info *)a;
>     struct FS_Info *entryB = (struct FS_Info *)b;
>
>     return (entryB->size - entryA->size);
> }
> ```

Although our program is a single translation unit, it's good to get into the habit of declaring them with internal linkage (using the `static` keyword) if they are not intended to be shared with other TUs.

Don't cast away `const` like that.  In fact, it's safer to just use implicit conversion from `const void*` which will fail to compile if you omit `const`.

We do nothing to avoid the subtraction overflowing, which causes Undefined Behaviour.  The standard idiom to avoid that is to subtract the results of two comparisons:

```
static int compare(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    const struct FS_Info *a = pa;
    const struct FS_Info *b = pb;

    return (b->size > a->size) - (a->size > b->size);
}
```

---

Usability could be better.  For example, when `realloc()` fails, we do this:

> ```
>             puts("An error occurred when attempting to resize the array!");
>             exit(-1);
> ```

But "resizing the array" is meaningless to the user, who knows nothing about the implementation.  Think about what they need to know.  And program exit codes are normally small *positive* integers; on Linux systems at least, that `-1` will end up converted to a larger positive number.

I'd replace that code with

```
            fputs("error: Out of memory\n", stderr);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Another usability improvement would be to default the program argument to use the current directory if none was specified, rather than printing to standard output and then proceeding to dereference a null pointer.

---

I don't like the magic numbers scattered through the program, especially `char name[1024]` and `char path_to_entry[1024]`.  On many systems, that's insufficient for a path name, and I don't see any guard to prevent buffer overrun.

---

Sorting the full list of files requires enough memory to hold `FS_Info` structures for all these files simultaneously, but we can avoid this unlimited reallocation.  There's a quick fix: where we currently reallocate, we could  sort the entries and discard all but the top ten, leaving empty space to read in another batch.  A more involved, but better, implementation is to stop using `qsort()` and instead implement a **heap**, retaining only the top ten items at all times.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've replaced `char path_to_entry[1024]` with `char path_to_entry[PATH_MAX]` as this seems like a platform independent way of ensuring a given path will have sufficient space. I'm also using `snprintf()` to read a path name as it guards against buffer overflow.  Next, I will implement a heap.

Comment: Paths can still exceed `PATH_MAX`, so you can't forego the checking!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you building a giant list of file sizes and then sorting them?  Why should this program chew up memory like that?  You want the 10 largest files, you need an array that will hold the 10 largest file sizes and pointers to their names.  No more.

Compare the size of the current file to the size of the smallest of the 10 and if it is less, drop it and move on.  If it is larger than that file, compare it to the next smallest and keep walking up the list.  Once you determine it is going to be one of the top 10, you can use bsearch to figure out where in the top 10 it goes as efficiently as possible.

Malloc isn't free, realloc less so, Allocate N slots for the top N largest files on the stack with alloca and don't use any more memory than that.  You only need enough memory for each of the 10 files you will print + the current filename you are working on.  Each of the filenames can reuse a buffer unless the size of the name is longer than the previous name.

Comment: Just noticed that @Toby flagged the storage problem I just pointed out.  Oops

Comment: One - this was a good learning experience for the poster. Two using your logic why even `malloc()` the memory, an array declared in the code would be good enough. You might want to explain why memory allocation is expensive (occasional system calls). Plus one because it is a decent answer. You might want to read https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778

Answer (score 1):

> Please critique not only my use of dynamic memory allocation,

**No need for any dynamic memory allocation.**

Top level code only needs

```
#deifne TOP_N 10
struct FS_Info Top[TOP_N];

char path_to_entry[1024];
```

**Magic numbers**

Why `1024`?  Typical file systems offset some `MAX_PATH_NAME` or the like.

**Error Checking**

Code like `snprintf(path_to_entry, sizeof(path_to_entry), "%s/%s", currDir, entry->d_name);` does not detect an insufficient buffer.

**Weak file size**

File sizes can readily exceed `INT_MAX`. Use the same type  in `struct stat st` or a wider type than `int`.

```
// int size;
long long size;
```